# Visual Studio 2012-Update 2 Won't Load Solution if SUO File is Present

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I develop in VS 2012/.NET on several computers (all running Windows 8 Pro x64). Although VS is installed on all computers I keep the project folder on an external USB3 drive. Every once in a while I would find the project files had been corrupted on the USB drive (e.g. cross-linked). Fortunately I keep frequent backups but clearly this situation is intolerable, so I set out trying to find what the issue(s) might be.

I still don't have a clear answer but one piece of strange behavior is this: if I open the .SLN file for my project in VS 2012 when an .SUO file is NOT present it loads fine, builds are OK, etc. HOWEVER, if I then save the project, exit VS (so an SUO file is created) and then attempt to REOPEN the solution VS hangs at (....loading). I get the usual "Visual Studio is busy....." messages and there is no point in waiting, the solution just never loads. I have to kill VS in TM. I've tested this repeatedly, and I've even done it from the local hard disk (as opposed to the USB drive) to see if USB was the problem. It isn't. Remember, this is all on the same computer (so as to remove "moving" as the cause of the issue). The only way I can work with the project is to delete the SUO file before trying to open it.

I would assume, if this was a VS bug, it would be pretty much all over the web and my searches would have turned up something. So I'm asking if anyone has any idea what the problem might be or if there are links that might help me figure things out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your VS installations identical? Same extensions etc? (That said, `.suo` files just might not be designed to be portable between machines - mine certainly contains absolute paths.)

Comment: Thank you for posting. I think the problem has been resolved, but I'm not sure of the exact cause. One thing that occurred to me was that maybe there was a problem with the solution so the SUO file being generated was corrupt. I cleaned the Solution. On top of that my USB3 disk finally became unreadable (it was subtly corrupt), so I reformatted it. Once I did both those things I have had no more issues (up to now). :) So SUO files seem to be portable. I don't know what caused the disk problems in the first place, I'm careful now when switching among VMs.

Comment: With USB3 drivers, I'd be careful: take a large (4GB) file and copy it back and forth, verifying checksums.  Also, what is the disk write policy?

Comment: same issue here, spent hours searching for a solution. no success yet. i just get the message "operation could not be completed" though.

Comment: Same issue, if the .suo is present the solution will try to load and then it will frozen at some point. No error message I have to close the process, delete the .suo and then it will load.

Comment: Yup, Im in the same boat with VS2015. I can't figure out why it wont load. There are errors in the VS log if I start it from the command line using the logging switch but they don't help me at all. How can I rebuild a solution file that is under source control?

Comment: Same issue here and only for my user. My collegues can open the solution with non problems.